# showing ManytoManyField element in a query loop

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

So I want to show elements in a loop from a class I created, however I don't know how to call the ManyToMany element out, can you help me?

```
class Tag(models.Model):
nametag = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

class OA(models.Model):
tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
...
```

My function:

```
def home(request):
objetos = OA.objects.all()
return render(request, {'objetos': objetos})
```

The problem:

```
{% for i in objetos %}
...
<tr>{{i.tags.nametag}}</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

In this case 'nametag' already has a value so it's not empty. I tried a few things but wasn't able to do much, I need help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enumerate over the `i.tags.all()`. Indeed, since this is a `ManyToManyField`, an `OA` can have zero, one, or more related `Tag`s, and a `Tag` can have zero, one or more `OA` objects.

You thus can implement this with;

```
<tr>{% for tag in i.tags.all %} {{ tag.nametag }}{% endfor %}</tr>
```

In the view, you can prefetch the related `Tag`s to avoid making an extra query *per* `OA` object:

```
def home(request):
    objetos = OA.objects.prefetch_related('tags')
    return render(request, {'objetos': objetos})
```

Comment: You can still present all attributes of the `i` object, so if `OA` has a field named `foo`, you can render this with `{{ i.foo }}`.